# RDP file setting: "use redirection server name"

Tags: rdp

Can anybody offer an explanation for the "use redirection server name" setting in an RDP file? It can be set as either:

```
use redirection server name:i:1
```

or

```
use redirection server name:i:0
```

I have a small number of clients for whom connections via an RD Gateway > Session Broker > Session Host will fail with 0x607 and a very large number where there are no problems.

For the broken client group, changing this setting from 1 to 0 will allow connections to succeed but I'd like to understand **why**.

Clients are spread across 3 different partner organisations with their own IT departments, so I will need to build a compelling case if we need to get a change in their environments.

My best guess is that it directs the client to either ignore or consider the FQDN of the connection broker against the certificate presented by either the broker or the target session host...

Thanks in advance!